# Reusable model in repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I've recently come across the problem of having multiple database types which should be swappable. My solution for this would be the repository pattern.
Having models like these.

```
class Book {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
class Author {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Having these two classes as my model.
And the following method in my repository.

```
class AuthorRepository {
    IEnumerable<Author> GetAll() {
        return Context.Set<Author>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Now I've got a few problems. First would be that using the repository like this.

```
using(var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new MyContext())) {
    MyObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Author>(unitOfWork.Authors.GetAll());
}
```

If I were to try and access the books inside the author model I would get a ObjectDisposedException. Which is obvious since books can only be accessed inside of the DbContext so the property should really only be used inside of the repository and not outside.

Now my second issue is that when I want to change from entity framework to another persistence framework the virtual methods would not work since (again as far as I am aware) this is only used in entity framework.

The setup shown above is how I've seen the repository pattern implemented just about everywhere, but I don't see the use in the pattern when I need to change my model whenever I want to change the persistence framework.

My fix would be the following.

```
class Author {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class EntityFrameworkAuthor : Author {
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

The EF author would only be used in the repositories and the Author would be returned to the business layer.

Now to my questions.

1. Is the method shown above the right way to use the repository pattern if I want to be able to switch frameworks easily (which I assumed the repository pattern was for).
2. Is my fix a good way to improve my current model? Or does it break the pattern in some way?
3. If not how would I go about making my model reusable for different persistence frameworks.

Comment: "since books can only be accessed inside of the DbContext so the property" How come EF doesn't return fully populated Authors with their book eagerly?

Comment: @plalx This is because the property is virtual, this allows entity framework to lazy load navigation properties.

Comment: @plalx This could be fixed by using Include but it's not really what i'm looking for. The main issue is still that the navigation properties are entity framework specific thus breaking the abstraction of the repository pattern (in my opinion).

Comment: It's not broke, but the implementation must be much much more complex. Lazy-loading entity data is a code smell to me and usually indicates that your data aggregation is wrong. You should only aggregate the smallest amount of data necessary to enforce business rules transactionnaly, not less, not more and in those conditions it makes sense to always load data eagerly. Also do not forget that objects are most useful to process commands and protect invariants of complex domains. I wouldn't shove data in business objects for queries (you may use DTOs though).

Comment: @plalx I don't think i fully understand. Lazy loading only happens in the repository (in my fixed version atleast), and then I return the Author class for example which contains only a name, is this not minimal data aggregation?

Comment: No it's not. If the data is not used in business logic conditions to protect the state of the aggregate (data cluster) to which it belongs and this data could exist on it's own then it shouldn't be aggregated. For instance, a Post normally shouldn't hold a collection of Comment objects even though we always say a Post has Comments. That is because there is usually no business rules that applies to a Post and all it's comments. Therefore, Post and Comment should be modeled as seperate aggregates and referenced by identity only.

Comment: Well-model aggregates will usually not need any form of lazy-loading. I'd recommend you to read these articles: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think breaking your model in two is a good idea. Personally I always think in terms of having the business logic completely unaware of the persistence logic.

You can do that via repository pattern which should be used in this way: you create the repository class with just the basic methods and then you add new methods as you need it.
**The reason for this is that you want each repository to be an abstraction of the mechanism used by your persistence layer to load the data.**
(here's a [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-cplusdoneplusright) that I found usefull about the repository pattern)

What I mean is that from the business layer point of view the method used to load, for example, *"all Author that wrote a book in 1974"* could be implemented within your code, as a stored procedure or everything else; as long as the business object that requested that set of data gets what it wants, it doesn't (and shouldn't) care.

With your solution however, you're making domain objects aware of the way data are accessed.
Personally, if the need is to be able to change ORM in the future, I would prefer to have something like a FacadeActorRepository that uses a concrete implementation EfActorRepository that you'll be able to switch as you change your ORM.

As for the lazy loading issue, as [plalx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211528/plalx) pointend out in the comments, (quote)

> "If the data is not used in business logic conditions to protect the
>   state of the aggregate (data cluster) to which it belongs and this
>   data could exist on it's own then it shouldn't be aggregated"

which means that if Author really needs a list of Books, you shouldn't allow it to be lazy loaded, but you should have it as soon as the Author object is finished being created.

I hope this helps :)